# How can I select a specific version of the root folder (.) in a snapshot view (Base ClearCase 7.1.2.9, no UCM)?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, config-spec

Stumbled over this at work yesterday: I have a small VOB and created a snapshot view to access the data (source files) in it. If I give the ConfigSpec as:

```
load /vob/extern
element * CHECKEDOUT

element * /main/LATEST
```

, I will see all elements in their "LATEST" version and running a `cleartool describe` or `xlsvtree` on a single element can confirm this. Fine.

There is a `src` folder at the top level, having the versions "0-2", and when I setup the ConfigSpec as

```
load /vob/extern
element * CHECKEDOUT

element src /main/1
element * /main/LATEST
```

I can select the "1" version of the `src` directory, while keeping all other elements at "LATEST". Super.

However, this doesn't seem to work with the root folder (versions "0-7"). When I edit the ConfigSpec to

```
load /vob/extern
element * CHECKEDOUT

element . /main/6
element * /main/LATEST
```

, the version "6" of "." doesn't get selected (it's at "7"=LATEST again)! How can I accomplish this in a snapshot view?

I have also made the following, admittedly desperate, attempts

```
element "." /main/6
```

and

```
element "\." /main/6
```

, but to no avail. Searched the web/stackoverflow for quite a while and the man pages for "`version_selector`", "`config_spec`" and "`wildcards_ccase`" didn't offer me any explanation for the current behaviour.

I also tried another

```
rm -rf *
cleartool update
```

after setting the ConfigSpec, but the version of "." stays at "7".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative path '`.`' does not seem to work, and the config spec falls back to the next valid rule.

Try and use, after reading [config_spec Pattern](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/8.0.1?topic=information-config-spec#ref_configspec_refsect2_8062553), an absolute path:

```
element /vob/extern  /main/6
# or
element /vob/extern/ /main/6
```

Comment: Yes, found that also by myself...a few seconds ago. And it works! Yay! Do you (by any chance) know of any other options to specify the root folder in this scenario?

Comment: @dirkbaechle I would try '`/`', just in case, but if it does not work, then the absolute path remains the best option.